# Sample $k$ of $n$ numbers (with replacement), what is the probability for a certain from the $n$ numbers to be the median of the $k$ numbers

Tags: probability, statistics, median

Suppose we have ordered numbers $a_1 < a_2 < \dots < a_n$. Now we sample $k$ of them with equal probability and with replacement and compute the median of these and call it $m$. (Let us assume that $k$ is odd for the sake of simplicity.) What is the probability the $m = a_i$ for each $i$?

I want to know this to construct the probability mass function for the median of $k$ random draws from a sample of $n$ numbers.

Comment: Well assuming $k=2\ell+1$ is odd, then $a_i$ is the median of the chosen numbers if and only if (1) $a_i$ is chosen, (2) $\ell$ of the other chosen numbers are $\leq a_i$, and (3) the remaining $\ell$ chosen numbers are $\geq a_i$. Computing the probability of that seems quite messy though.

Comment: That's how far I got, too... Thanks, for putting it down clearly. If anybody can provide an algorithm to compute it instead of an equation I would also be happy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $m$ is the median of $k$ samples, and $u$ is the number of samples $\le m$, then

$$P(m \le a_i) = \frac{1}{n^k}\sum_{u=(k+1)/2}^k \binom{k}{u}\, i^u\, (n-i)^{k-u}$$
$$P(m = a_i) = P(m \le a_i) - P(m \le a_{i-1})$$

$$\ $$
A good test case is $n=4, i=2, k=3$ for which we can list the relevant cases.

The median is 1 if the samples are the

- 1 permutation of 111
- 3 permuations of 112
- 3 permutations of 113
- 3 permutations of 114

for a total probability of 10/64, which agrees with the formula.

The median is 2 if the samples are the

- 3 permutations of 122
- 6 permutations of 123
- 6 permutations of 124
- 1 permutation  of 222
- 3 permutations of 223
- 3 permutations of 224

for a total probability of 22/64, which also agrees with the formula.

Comment: $$p_i = \frac{1}{n^k}\sum_{u=0}^{k'}\binom{k}{u}(i-1)^u\sum_{w=0}^{k'}\binom{k-u}{w}(n-i)^w$$ with $0^0=1$

Comment: It seems to me an issue is "collisions", as in some $a_i$ might be chosen more than once. This then skews the median, no?

Comment: @ClaudeChaunier, now I understand, and I’ve deleted my earlier comments